docker inspect & entrypoint as arguments
I have following small Dockerfile
ARG base_image=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet
ARG base_image_version=8.0

# Use a runtime image as the base image
FROM ${base_image}:${base_image_version} AS runtime

# The name of DLL which needs to be used for starting the application
ARG DLL_NAME

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the published application from the build stage into the runtime image
COPY . ./

RUN echo "DLL to execute: ${DLL_NAME}"

# Expose the port that the application will listen on
EXPOSE 80

# Define the entry point for the container
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "${DLL_NAME}"]

I'm calling docker build with --build-arg DLL_NAME=TodoApi.dll
The Output of log shows as expected DLL to execute: TodoApi.dll but docker inspect shows "Entrypoint": [ "dotnet","${DLL_NAME}" ].
I would expect that the dll name is shoen there.
What I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks
Joerg

Is there a reason you need the $DLL_NAME to be configurable?  I'd expect that it'd be fixed based on what's being built into the image, and I'd just hard-code it.

The reason is: reuseability.

Try this   ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "dotnet $DLL_NAME"]

thank you for the idea. I have test it and docker inspect still shows "Entrypoint": [                "sh", "-c", "dotnet $DLL_NAME" ]
